# .NET 6 EF 6.4. No connection string named 'xxx' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector, .net-6.0

I'm creating a new C# WebApi project using .NET 6 and Entity Framework 6.4.4 **(not EF Core)** and MySql v8 using MySql Connector.net v8.

When I try to enable the migrations I get the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named
> 'EntitiesContext' could be found in the application config file.

**This is a solution with a single project! I don't have the EntitiesContext in a separated project.**

Here's my *EntitiesContext* class

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class EntitiesContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<C_Prod> C_Prod { get; set; }

    // using this constructor the migrations don't work
    public EntitiesContext()
        : base("name=EntitiesContext")
    {
    }

    // using this constructor the migrations work as expected
    //public EntitiesContext()
    //  : base("server=localhost;database=mytests;user=root;password=123")
    //{
    //}
}
```

Here's the web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
            </provider>
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EntitiesContext" connectionString="server=localhost;database=mytests;user=root;password=123" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Here's the program.cs file

```
using WebApplicationCSharp;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("EntitiesContext");
builder.Services.AddScoped<EntitiesContext>(_ => new EntitiesContext());

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

and here's the appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EntitiesContext": "server=localhost;database=mytests;user=root;password=123"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Why EF can't find the connection string in the web.config file?

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. .NET Core doesn't use web.config *at all*. Either switch to EF Core 6 or pass the connection string to the DbContext's constructor explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a viable workaround to avoid hardcoding the connection string.

Create a constructor where you specify the connection string

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class EntitiesContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<C_Prod> C_Prod { get; set; }

    public EntitiesContext(string connString)
      : base(connString)
    {
    }
}
```

Then create an implementation of the interface *IDbContextFactory* where is hardcoded the connection string. This class is used in design time when EF create migrations. You don't need to instantiate it. EF will instantiate it automagically using reflection.

```
public class MigrationsContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<EntitiesContext>
{
    public EntitiesContext Create()
    {
        return new EntitiesContext("server=localhost;database=mytests;user=root;password=123");
    }
}
```

Now in the program.cs file you can get the connection string from the appsetings.json and use it in the EntitiesContext constructor

```
// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("EntitiesContext");

builder.Services.AddScoped<EntitiesContext>(_ => new EntitiesContext(connectionString));
```

Here's the appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EntitiesContext": "server=localhost;database=mytests;user=root;password=123"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be old, but I'm just doing some support on such an old system:

instead of:

```
public EntitiesContext()
    : base("name=EntitiesContext")
```

just use

```
public EntitiesContext()
    : base("EntitiesContext")
```

and you should be good to go.